# Can VMD change its cartoon representation for secondary structure according to trajectories?

Tags: vmd

I am using `VMD` to visualise the secondary structure of protein [here](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/).

The trajectories are from my Gromacs simulation. Firstly I use `File - New Molecule...` to load the `protein.gro` file. Secondly I use `File - Load Data into Molecule...` to load my `protein.xtc` trajectories.

Then I use `Cartoon` to visulise the structure. As I drag the time frames, all the secondary structures (e.g. alpha-helix, beta-sheet) stay the same. But I am pretty sure some of them are changing, as I look into the `Timeline` analysis for secondary structure.

So how do I use `VMD` to see the secondary structures at different time frames?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, It can. Just run this script in `Extensions --> TK console` of vmd before visualizing

```
proc structure_trace {name index op} {
      vmd_calculate_structure $index
}

trace variable vmd_frame w structure_trace
```